# How to publish media (image) on Mastodon using API?

Tags: php, api, media

I'm trying to POST an image on Mastodon (specifically on Humblr) but I cannot get the media_id, the response is null, but I'm not sure where the problem is.

I can publish text, no problem, so the authentication part is fine, I only have the problem with the image, the only difference I can see in the [documentation](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/api/rest/media/#post-api-v1-media) is that "Media file encoded using multipart/form-data".
Here's my code so far...

```php
$headers = ['Authorization: Bearer '.$settings['access_token'] , 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'];

  $mime_type = mime_content_type($urlImage);                     
  $cf = curl_file_create($urlImage,$mime_type,'file');
  $media_data = array(  "file" => $cf);

  $ch_status = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch_status, CURLOPT_URL, "https://humblr.social/api/v1/media");   
  curl_setopt($ch_status, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch_status, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $media_data);
  curl_setopt($ch_status, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch_status, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $media_status = json_decode(curl_exec($ch_status));
  echo "Response: ".json_encode($media_status);
```

From this I want to extract the $media_status-> media_id

I don't really know much about 'multipart/form-data' to be honest.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took some trial and error for me as well. Here's what worked for me (PHP 7.3):

```php
$curl_file = curl_file_create('/path/to/file.jpg','image/jpg','file.jpg');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://instanceurl.com/api/v1/media');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE',
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
]);

$body = [
  'file' => $curl_file
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$response) {
  die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

echo 'HTTP Status Code: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Response Body: ' . $response . PHP_EOL;

curl_close($ch);
```